# Magento2: How to generate warehouse report

Tags: magento2

I need to generate a magazine report for the product selection.

Product name, sku, quantity, price etc. for selected products. How can this be done?

Comment: Did my answer https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/260959/76597 help you to solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You may create a sql statement joining `catalog_product_entity`, `cataloginventory_stock_item` for sku and stock related data and `eav_attribute`, `catalog_product_entity_XXX` (XXX is the type of the requested attribute, for example `varchar` for `name`) for each product attribute you need.

Example for sku, name, qty:

```
select p.sku, s.qty, nv.value as name
from catalog_product_entity p
join cataloginventory_stock_item s on p.entity_id = s.product_id
join eav_attribute na on na.entity_type_id = 4 and na.attribute_code = 'name'
join catalog_product_entity_varchar nv on nv.attribute_id = na.attribute_id and 
nv.entity_id = p.entity_id;
```